Please add tag BIP85
There are some existing questions on this topic.
The tag would make them easier to surface.

Sure, no problem. I've added bip85-deterministic-entropy  to a few questions where it seemed to fit.

Wow look what happened!! https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/112528/132451
